# Figuring out location of a loaded shared library

Tags: c, shared-library, dynamic-linking, elf

I'm maintaining a C-program, that uses Oracle client libraries. The libraries expect the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable to be set, and fail to work without it -- in many cases.

In our situation, the value of the variable is always derived from the location of the shared libraries themselves anyway -- and I'd like to implement setting it from the C-code (using `putenv(3)`).

But, for that, I need to know, from where a particular shared library used by the program was loaded.
So, if `ldd`, when applied to the executable file, outputs:

```
libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x1021000)
libmeow.so.1 => /opt/meow/lib/libmeow.so.1
```

How can the running process itself find out, that `libmeow.so`, which it is using, is loaded from `/opt/meow/lib`?

The answer needn't be universally-portable -- something, that'd work for just Linux and BSD will suffice.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux you can read and search through pseudo file `/proc/<pid>/maps`, where `<pid>` would be `self` from a program looking at itself. It has lines for each memory mapped item, which should include each shared library, eg

```
7f63c2c23000-7f63c2dd0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136321  /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so
```

See `man proc` for details.

---

There is also a C api for a program to walk through the list of shared objects it is using. See `man dl_iterate_phdr`. It provides an example of its use. For your use case it is as simple as this:

```C
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <link.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static int callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data){
    if(info->dlpi_name[0]!='\0')printf("%s\n", info->dlpi_name);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    dl_iterate_phdr(callback, NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The `dl_iterate_phdr` method is perfect. Works on Linux and BSD. Would, likely, work on Solaris too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the libraries, linked in particular binary can be found with command `ldd`. For example:

```
$ldd /bin/cp
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffaf3ff000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003a06a00000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003a06200000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x0000003a13000000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x0000003a0ea00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003a05200000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003a05a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003a04a00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003a05600000)
```

From this place you can filter the Oracle libraries and set accordingly `ORACLE_HOME` variable. All this can be done in script which will run your program with already set variable.

Comment: I know, I can do this. My question was, how to perform this lookup from inside the running program. How would the process do it on itself?

Comment: @MikhailT., why do not do this in advance, in shell script?

Comment: because shell-wrappers are _ugly_. We have enough of them already for programs, which we do not control. But this particular one is ours, and it can do the right thing by itself.

Comment: @MikhailT., for me changing environment in C program is **ugly** :D

Comment: This is something, the program requires -- and should be doing itself. The not doing is ugly -- not, where it is implemented. In my opinion...